# JSON selector `field->key` causes syntax error in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I have dates like this :- $startdate= 10/23/2017 and $enddate =10/28/2017 ..need to compare with database table key name availablityschedule which is in serialize form like a:2:{s:10:"start_date";s:10:"2017-07-24";s:8:"end_date";s:10‌​:"2017-07-31";}

Comment: Is this a serialised object?

Comment: That's not JSON

Comment: Seriously this question is not clear. It will only attract random answers

Answer (score 1):

If all your dates are posterior to the 1st of January of 1970, you could use something like:

```
$startDate= date("Y-m-d");
$endDate = $JSONObject->endDate

$startDate = strtotime($startDate);
$endDate = strtotime($endDate);

if ($endDate < $startDate) { /* do Something */ }
```

If you are using PHP > 5.0 you can use the class DateTime

```
$today_dt = new DateTime($startDate);
$expire_dt = new DateTime($endDate);

if ($expire_dt < $today_dt) { /* Do something */ }
```

Asuming of course you would like to do this in the `backend` side with php.

Comment: I have dates like this :- $startdate= 10/23/2017 and $enddate =10/28/2017      ..need to compare with database table key name availablityschedule which is in  serialize form like a:2:{s:10:"start_date";s:10:"2017-07-24";s:8:"end_date";s:10:"2017-07-31";}

Comment: I'm not remembering any function of the DateTime to convert `18/12/18` format to `18-12-18` but you could do it yourself: `$startDate = explode("/", $startDate); $standardDate = $startDate[0] ."-". $startDate[1] ."-". $startDate[2];` `$standardDate` will have your date as `18-12-18` format

Comment: simple example : $val ="5"; and colum value in table like this {s:5:"2,4,5"};->where([['{s:5:"2,4,5"}','=',$val]]); in laravel

Comment: Search from serialized field in mysql database  laravel5.4